# .net core Dockerfile issue / MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist

Tags: msbuild, dockerfile

[Below is the output of the Error when i build a Dockerfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hF8q4.png)

My Dockerfile seems like that :

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:6.0 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app
# copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore
# copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out
# build runtime image
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:6.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY — from=build-env /app/out .
EXPOSE 80/tcp
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "AuditModule.dll"]
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please format your code fragments (which I done for you). Also, please provide error messages as text instead of images.

Comment: Provide also the project folder structure.